# Required request body is missing Spring boot Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, postman

I want to post data to my Spring boot API webservice this is my function in the Rest Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/update_version")
public String updateVersion(@RequestBody String type, @RequestBody String buildId,
        @RequestBody String imageName, @RequestBody String remoteDirectory,
        @RequestBody String backupPath) {

    return historyService.updateVersion(type, buildId, imageName, remoteDirectory, backupPath);
}
```

I tried post with angular front project.I thought it could a problem with it so i tried with postman:
[image]
How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The request must have only one RequestBody**.

You cannot use multiple `@RequestBody` in your method parameters, this is cannot be done with Spring Boot, you can only use it once.

**Solution**:

**1-** Create a Model class named for example **History** (according to your request)

**2-** Specify all your needed attributes like this

```
public class History {

private String type;

@JsonProperty("build_id")
private String buildId;

@JsonProperty("image_name")
private String imageName;

@JsonProperty("remote_directory")
private String remoteDirectory;

@JsonProperty("backup_path")
private String backupPath;

//Getters + Setters + Constructor(s) etc ...
```

}

**3-** The method signature will be like this

```
@PostMapping(value = "/update_version")
public String updateVersion(@RequestBody History history) { ... }
```

Comment: I will try that with my existing model class History.The problem is "remote_directory" and "image_name" does not belong to History class but to Project class